# Zend framework invalid date

Tags: zend-framework

I am using Zend framework for the site which sends email for the voucher order with a pdf attachment in the email. Everything work fine with the site but the Expiry date sending to the pdf alone have problems. I have passed the expiry date parameter from my database table values but it always takes the some default value of 1-1-1970. I have used the following set of codes for the pdf attachment with the email.

```
    $endDate = new Zend_Date();
    $endDate->set($data['voucher']['enddate']);
    $endDate= $endDate->toString('dd/MM/YYYY');

    //build PDF voucher attachment
    $at = $this->generateVoucherPDFAttachement($recipientName, $customerName, $data['order']['msg'], $order['vouchercode'], $endDate);

     $this->_helper->Mail(array(
            'smile@ipressprinting.com.au' => 'Smile@iPress',
            'info@ipressprinting.com.au' => 'Info@iPress',
                ), 'New voucher order #' . $data['order']['id'], $mailMsg, $at);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which is the format of `$data['voucher']['enddate']`? You should take care of it when building a `Zend_Date` object, otherwise it will use an heuristic based on current locale to parse the date given.

Usually if the date comes from a db field (i.e. yyyy-mm-dd) you can build a Zend_Date in this way:

```
$date = new Zend_Date('2011-08-24', 'yyyy-MM-dd');
print_r($date->get(Zend_Date::DATE_FULL));
```

Comment: I have checked the database the date is in the format of yyyy-MM-dd pnly. Changed the code but still the pdf is showing 1/1/1970
$endDate = new Zend_Date($data['voucher']['enddate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd');
$endDate->get(Zend_Date::DATE_FULL);
$endDatenew = $endDate->toString('dd/MM/YYYY');

Comment: @Anandhan if `$endDate` variable hold the correct date then your problem must be in your pdf generation code. Check the `generateVoucherPDFAttachement`, the answer is there.

Comment: :The date problem have been fixed now, but  i need to send the email attachment based on the number of quantiy given as input. If they give quantity as 5 then need to send one email with 5different PDf attachments with the differnt in the voucherid.I am having the unique voucherid and quantity number in the database.Ex: the first attachment pdf will have Voucherid:WER1, 2nd pdf voucherid:WER2, etc.Email code :$this->_helper->mail($sendTo['email'], 'Voucher Present', $mailMsg, $at);

Comment: You can safely add more than one attachment, see [example 1 here](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.mail.attachments.html). If you're having troubles in that I think you should open a different question.